# VB issue with DataTable.ImportRow() method

Tags: vb.net, datatable

When filling a DataTable from another DataTable, I have noticed that a column gets an incorrect value.

VB code:

```
Dim DT1 as DataTable = ...
Dim DT2 as DataTable = ...

DT2.Rows.Clear()
For Each row In DT1.Rows
 DT2.ImportRow(row)
 If (DT2.Rows.Item(DT2.Rows.Count - 1).Item("MyProp") <> row.Item("MyProp")) Then
  'This condition is true!!!!
 End If
Next
```

How can this possibly happen?

Even stranger is that

`DT2.Rows.Item(DT2.Rows.Count - 1).Item("MyProp")`  = the older value that has been cleared with 
`DT2.Rows.Clear()`

I am 100% sure that `Clear()` method did clear all the rows as I watched values content into the debugger.

Comment: You should really get familiar with `Option Strict`. Normally you can't compare two objects with `<>`. What type is `MyProp`? Also, you could use `DT2.Clear` although i think it's the same as `DT2.Rows.Clear()`.

Comment: MyProp type is double

Comment: Use `DT2.Clear` to clear the data table.

Comment: And your if statement should be this `If (DT2.Rows(DT2.Rows.Count - 1)("MyProp") <> row("MyProp")) Then`

Comment: Same results with DT2.Clear()than with DT2.Rows.Clear()

Comment: As per the condition, values are stillcompletely different if I use your writing instead of the one of the original post:
In mycase, 

If (DT2.Rows(DT2.Rows.Count - 1)("MyProp") = 916

row("MyProp")) =2600

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. 
You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime and lead you to...

```
    For Each row As DataRow In DT1.Rows
        DT2.ImportRow(row)
        If CDbl(DT2.Rows(DT2.Rows.Count - 1).Item("MyProp")) <> CDbl(row.Item("MyProp")) Then
            'Do something
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thx for the general tip.
Same results after changing 


For Each row In DT1.Rows


for


For Each row As DataRow In DT1.Rows

Comment: and setting turing option"strict" on did not change the behaviour either.